# C++ bindings to Marmalade Quick not work in Android

Tags: lua, marmalade, marmalade-quick

I read reference "Adding your own C++ Bindings to Quick". And when I unpacked "tolua++.Mac.zip" and did all steps of reference I can run example in simulator. 
But when I prebuild quickuser for "GCC ARM Release" and "GCC ARM Debug" I can't run example in android.
P.S.: I use Mac OS Maverics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found answer. This is buf of Marmalade's "quick_prebuild". It is wrong path in build phase "s3e_plink": "/Applications/Marmalade.app/Contents/quick/target/osx/quick_prebuilt_d.s3e" instead of "/Applications/Marmalade.app/Contents/quick/target/arm/quick_prebuilt_d.s3e".